# Polygon Collision Testing / Polygon Overlap Test in C# - Not Point in Polygon

Tags: c#, collision-detection, overlapping, point-in-polygon

I am testing to determine if two polygons overlap. I have developed a first version which does a simple point in polygon test (Fig 1). However I am looking to revamp that method to deal with situations where no vertices of polygon A are in polygon B but their line segments overlap (Fig B).

Any help getting started would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: All you need to do is the opposite point in polygon test. i.e. `var isCollision = IsPointInPolygon(a,b) || IsPointInPolygon(b,a)`

Comment: Mike, Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Using the example image that you have shown in Fig 2 the triangle does not have a point in the rectangle; however, the rectangle has a point in the triangle. If two polygons overlap then one of them will have a point in another. Check if A has a point in B as well as if B has a point in A, if either is true then there is a collision, if neither is true then they are not touching.

Comment: As soon as I commented I realized more fully what you were talking about. I am wondering however how this works with more complex polygons.

Comment: All complex polygons can be broken down into groups of triangles. I am not a collision guru so there may be a more efficient method here, but the quick and dirty way is to simply check all triangles from polygon A against B and then all from B against A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with using Region:

```
  GraphicsPath grp = new GraphicsPath();

  // Create an open figure
  grp.AddLine(10, 10, 10, 50); // a of polygon
  grp.AddLine(10, 50, 50, 50); // b of polygon
  grp.CloseFigure();           // close polygon

  // Create a Region regarding to grp
  Region reg = new Region(grp);
```

Now you can use the Method [Region.IsVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.isvisible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to determine whether the region is in an Rectangle or Point.

Comment: This might be too expensive computationally but worth a try.

Comment: After looking at the MSDN documentation, it appears this will only with with a polygon (as created by the GraphicsPath) and a rectangle or point structure. My need is to test polygon and polygon.

Comment: I ended up doing:

private Region FindIntersections(List<PolyRegion> regions)
{
    if (regions.Count < 1) return null;

    Region region = new Region();
    for (int i = 0; i < regions.Count; i++)
    {
      using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
      {
        path.AddPath(regions[i].Path, false);
        region.Intersect(path);
      }
    }

    return region;
}

Answer (score 1):

**The solution:**

I modified some code found [here](http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/08/23/find-the-area-where-two-or-more-circles-overlap-in-c.aspx).

```
private Region FindIntersections(List<PolyRegion> regions)
{
    if (regions.Count < 1) return null;

    Region region = new Region();
    for (int i = 0; i < regions.Count; i++)
    {
        using (GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath())
        {
            path.AddPath(regions[i].Path, false);
            region.Intersect(path);
        }
    }

    return region;
}
```

**The result:**

[image]